# GROUP_CONCAT is unsupported

Tags: ignite

I have found GROUP_CONCAT doc on official docs  https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs  (SQL REFERENCE / Aggregate Functions / GROUP_CONCAT), but it has not supported yet in ignite source code:

```
// GridSqlAggregateFunction.java:84
switch (type) {
  case GROUP_CONCAT:
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
```

Has plan to supporte it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function was added to the SQL reference by mistake and removed for now. To my knowledge Ignite community considers adding it in the future.